# What are the differences of Pool.map and Process in parallel programming in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to under stand the multiprocessing module. When should I use Pool.map over Process when I want to run a function several times consecutively with different arguments? What are the advantages and disadvantages of each?

Answer (score 0):

Pool.map spawns multiple process to achieve a certain task.

When you have tasks units which you want to work on in a separate process then you can directly spawn the process.

```
def execute_new_work(work=somefunction):
    p = multiprocessing.Process(target=work)
    p.start()
```

Pool can be used to manage a fixed number of workers.

When you have known amount of work units that you want to process using a same function but in parallel then instead of using `for loop`, you can use pool.map. This is just more convenient and easy

```
pool_size = multiprocessing.cpu_count() * 2
pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=pool_size,
                            initializer=start_process,
                           )
outputs = pool.map(workon_fucntion, inputs)
```

As you can see this is quite pythonic and reminiscence of the map function in Python. What you can do with map, you can do with `for loop`.

Only thing to note here is that worker processes are fixed in advance and pool manages the work distribution to the workers which is quite nice.

Comment: Should I use Process if I have multiple arguments and am running Python 2.6?

Comment: @idealistikz: No I think multiple argument should not be an issue either way. Determine if you need a constant pool of workers and not just one off requirement. If it is one off then you may waste the workers in pool for doing nothing. :)

Comment: Should I use Process if the function I am calling requires multiple arguments? If I am using Process in a for loop, isn't it spawning different processes based on the number of iterations?

Comment: yes, it does spawn a different process in each iteration but you still need to do the job keeping - track processes and output etc. it is quite elegant to use pool then.